# ASP.NET MVC System.Net.Mail with <strong></strong>

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I am sending emails via ASP.NET MVC System.Net.Mail and my email body has html tag in it `<strong></strong>` but when I send the email, the text looks like this `<strong>MESSAGE</strong>` instead of it being bold, how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
var message = "<strong>MESSAGE</strong>\n\n";
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email2@example.com);
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@example.com");
MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to);
email.Subject = "Subject Line";
email.Body = message;
email.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.example.com");
```

Comment: When you have a question about how something built into .NET works, check the [relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `IsBodyHtml` flag to `true`:

```
email.IsBodyHtml = true;
```